# Is there a "most efficient" approximation for $\pi$?

Tags: number-theory, approximation

Take the function $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\left|(\pi-x)*\textit{Den}(x)\right|$, where $\textit{Den}(x)$ denotes the denominator of $x$.

This function doesn't seem to have a global minimum, but I can't prove it. I found the [numerators](https://oeis.org/A002485) and [denominators](https://oeis.org/A002486) of the best rational approximations of $\pi$ and it seems that as these get better, this function keeps getting smaller.

**Has anyone got an idea how to prove that $f(x)$ doesn't have a global minimum?**

Comment: " I found the numerators and denominators of $\pi$ " - it has neither. What you found is a sequence of simple continued fraction convergents to $\pi$

Comment: What do you mean by "THE" denominator?

Comment: Are you familiar with irrationality measure? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html

Comment: @JuriyS sorry I meant the fractional approximations of course.

Comment: Simple continued fraction gives the best approximations for an irrational number for a given size of denominator